# How do you express this in simplest terms? $\tan\frac{\pi }{12}+\tan\frac{2\pi}{12}+\tan\frac{3\pi }{12}+\tan\frac{4\pi}{12}+\tan\frac{5\pi}{12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I express the following in the simplest terms?

> $$\tan\frac{\pi }{12}+\tan\frac{2\pi}{12}+\tan\frac{3\pi }{12}+\tan\frac{4\pi}{12}+\tan\frac{5\pi}{12}$$

Comment: What does it mean to solve this in the simplest terms?

Comment: @JamesMitchell I basically mean solve it.

Comment: There's no equation to *solve*. I believe you the word you want is "express".

Comment: Yes exactly, solve it for what?

Comment: Yes, there's a difference between words like "solve" "simplify" "evaluate". Is it necessary to hit precalc students on the head when they use the wrong word though?

Comment: Simplify the expression down as much as possible @ziggurism

Comment: The arguments in the middle three terms reduce to $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and $\frac{\pi}{3}$. The values of $\tan()$ at these "special" angles are usually familiar. (That's why the angles are called "special", after all.) The "hard" ones are $\frac{\pi}{12}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{12}$. If you can write these in terms of the "special" angles, then you can apply the formula for $\tan(\alpha \pm \beta)$; or, you can think of each as *half* of a "special" angle and apply the lesser-known formula for $\tan\frac{1}{2}\theta$.

Comment: Hint for $\tan{\frac{\pi}{12}}+\tan{\frac{5\pi}{12}}$: notice that $\frac{5\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{12}$, and so $\tan{\frac{5\pi}{12}} = \cot{\frac{\pi}{12}}$. Then $\tan{\frac{\pi}{12}} + \cot{\frac{\pi}{12}} = \frac{\sin(\pi/12)}{\cos(\pi/12)} + \frac{\cos(\pi/12)}{\sin(\pi/12)} = \frac{\sin^2(\pi/12)+\cos^2(\pi/12)}{\sin(\pi/12)\cos(\pi/12)}$.

Comment: Using $\tan\frac{\theta}{2} + \tan\frac{\pi-\theta}{2} = \frac{2}{\sin\theta}$, you can show the sum is $5 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$,